# Directory with .htpasswd is missing in directory listing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

Having multiple directories in a parent directory, if I add .htaccess (see below) to a child directory, this directory is no longer listed in the parent directory listing.

```
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "restricted area"
    AuthUserFile /home/www/example.cz/www/dokumentace/file/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
```

Can this be changed somehow? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the directory listing hides resources that would return 403 Forbidden:

> When a directory listing is produced, certain files will not be shown,
>   by default. Files and directories that have access restrictions placed
>   on them, either by password or by address, will not be shown in a
>   directory listing.
>
> If you want these files to be listed, you will need to set
>   IndexOptions ShowForbidden in the directory block in question. The
>   ShowForbidden setting is only available in 2.2 and later.
>
> Source: [Apache Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings#Some_files_aren.27t_listed)

So to summarize, you should add the following to your configuration (either globally or in the parent directory's `.htaccess`) if you are sure you want to show them:

```
IndexOptions ShowForbidden
```